# How do I properly deal with 1 dimensional input in Keras Conv1D?

Tags: python, keras

So I'm trying to train a model in Keras that takes in frames of signals that are of a shape `(750,1)`. My first layer is the following `Conv1D` layer:

```
Conv1D(128, 5,input_shape=(1,750) padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1)
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 5 from 1 for 'conv1d_1/convolution/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,1,1,750], [1,5,750,128].
```

Which seems to indicate that the layer is trying to apply a 5x5 kernel to the 1 dimensional data which doesn't make much sense. Any other input shapes just seem to throw different less useful errors. What am I doing wrong? Am I completely misunderstanding `Conv1D` ?

Comment: the interpretatino of shape (1, 750) depends on your configuration of channels ordering. It is most likely set to "channels last", which means you have a one sample signal with 750 channels.

Comment: I tried
`x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train),750,1))`

`x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test),750,1))`

and it seems to work, however Instead I get some weird tensorflow memory warnings and the training is extremely slow, warnings example:

`2017-07-05 15:44:36.756315: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\pool_allocator.cc:247] PoolAllocator: After 1005 get requests, put_count=2035 evicted_count=1000 eviction_rate=0.4914 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0` @MatiasValdenegro